# System of Gaussian equations

Tags: normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, interpolation

Let $N(x\ |\ \mu,\sigma^2)$ be the pdf of a normal random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Question: Given $n$ data points $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1,\dots,n}$, compute $\{w_i\}_i$,$\{\sigma_i^2\}_i$ that solve/approximate the following system of (non-linear) equations:

$y_i = \sum_{j=1}^n w_j\cdot N(x_i\ |\ x_j,\sigma_j^2),\quad i=1,\ldots,n$

Also, is there a unique solution if we assume a fixed $\sigma_i^2= \sigma^2$?

Comment: I see $N$ equations and $2N$ unknowns.   Is your question about how to describe the solution set (a variety of some sort)?

Comment: @Andrew M Ideally, yes, but a single solution will also do.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by the function $N(\mu, \sigma)$?  The normal density with mean $\mu$ and "variance" $\sigma$  (do you mean standard deviation?) is a function of three arguments: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-\frac{(z-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$.

Comment: @Andrew M You are right, the question was misleading. I've made corresponding edits.